# Import resources without forcing new ones being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to recover the state for an AWS account configured with terraform. I've ran 'terraform import' with my module and am able to pull in the state for a few aws_subnets, but when I run 'terraform plan' it still tries to force destroying the existing subnets and recreating them.

Here is how my terraform looks

```
  resource "aws_subnet" "instance_subnets" {
  for_each = { for idx, subnet in keys(var.subnets) : idx => { name = subnet
  cidr = var.subnets[subnet] } }
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = element(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, each.key)

  tags = {
    Name = each.value.name
  }
}
```

My terraform.tf

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "Public" : "10.10.0.0/24"
    "Private" : "10.10.1.0/24"
  }
```

The terraform plan output

```
  # module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
      - arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:0xxxxxxxxxxxxx:subnet/subnet-0000xxxxx" -> null
      - assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false -> null
      - availability_zone               = "eu-west-2a" -> null
      - availability_zone_id            = "euw2-az2" -> null
      - cidr_block                      = "10.10.0.0/24" -> null
      - id                              = "subnet-0000xxxxx" -> null
      - map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch = false -> null
      - map_public_ip_on_launch         = false -> null
      - owner_id                        = "0xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> null
      - tags                            = {
          - "Name" = "Public"
        } -> null
      - tags_all                        = {
          - "Name" = "Public"
        } -> null
      - vpc_id                          = "vpc-0000xxxxxxx" -> null

      - timeouts {}
    }

  # module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets[1] will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
      - arn                             = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:0xxxxxxxxxxxxx:subnet/subnet-0000xxxxx" -> null
      - assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false -> null
      - availability_zone               = "eu-west-2b" -> null
      - availability_zone_id            = "euw2-az3" -> null
      - cidr_block                      = "10.10.1.0/24" -> null
      - id                              = "subnet-0000xxxxx" -> null
      - map_customer_owned_ip_on_launch = false -> null
      - map_public_ip_on_launch         = false -> null
      - owner_id                        = "0xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> null
      - tags                            = {
          - "Name" = "Private"
        } -> null
      - tags_all                        = {
          - "Name" = "Private"
        } -> null
      - vpc_id                          = "vpc-0000xxxxxxx" -> null

      - timeouts {}
    }

  # module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = "eu-west-2a"
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.10.0.0/24"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + tags                            = {
          + "Name" = "Public"
        }
      + tags_all                        = {
          + "Name" = "Public"
        }
      + vpc_id                          = "vpc-0000xxxxxxx"
    }

  # module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets["1"] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = "eu-west-2b"
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.10.1.0/24"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + tags                            = {
          + "Name" = "Private"
        }
      + tags_all                        = {
          + "Name" = "Private"
        }
      + vpc_id                          = "vpc-0000xxxxxxx"
    }
```

I have ec2 instances that can't be terminated in each subnet so can't have it destroyed and recreated. Is it possible to import them in a way that will allow me to use the statefile as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index that `for_each` using is the index of the length of subnets variable, in normal `for_each` you should use the name index:

```
for_each = var.subnets
```

Then import with name index:

```
terraform import module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets["private"] SUBNET_ID
terraform import module.mymodule.aws_subnet.subnets["public"] SUBNET_ID
```

Read more here:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-resource-configured-with-for_each
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html